# get column mData keys from datatables object

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables

I am hoping to get the keys used to make columns in [datatables](https://www.datatables.net/)

e.g. 'user.first_name'

however using the datatable api I can't find it.

I can see things like columns() however I can't find the associated key used to map to the column title "First Name"

Any suggestions?

Comment: nevermind it was .dataSrc of each column

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found

```
dt.columns().every(function () {
 console.log( this.dataSrc())
})
```